# Wordpress 3.9 and jQuery Wildcard Selector Issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to implement a "checkall" with the following code:

```
<script>
    jQuery('.grpInclude').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var checkBoxes = jQuery('input[id=*"grpInc"]');
        checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    });
</script>
```

However, it keeps failing with: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id=*"grpInc"]`

I've also tried it as `input[id=^"grpInc"]` and it fails with the same issue.

What can I do to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for wildcards and attribute selectors:

```
jQuery("input[id^=grpInc]")
```